# Hotpoint 9 cycle washer won't finish draining after agitate cycle

Tags: washing-machine

My washer fills, then agitates, then drains out, but gets stuck draining. I can move the knob to get the machine to move to the next step in the cycle, but when it needs to drain again after the rinse, it won't stop draining. Again, I can move the knob to get it to spin out. The only issue I can detect is that the machine doesn't seem to know it's done draining. Thoughts?

Comment: Sometimes a confused washing machine can straighten itself out with a hard reboot: unplug, wait a full minute, plug back in.

Answer (score 1):

Water pressure level switch. The knob automatically turns based on inputs from various sensors and switches. It seems your pressure switch gets stuck in a high pressure reading with the model of your unit I can be more specific, here's a link of what the problem likely is. https://www.thespruce.com/repair-washing-machine-water-level-fill-switch-1824607
This is possibly what you are looking for. 
[image]